# Library or Ideas on Exporting Images from Website as JPG and/or PDF

Tags: php

I have a website that generates BMP image files (graphs) from database data. I'd like to give the user the ability to download just the image(graph) as a JPG and a PDF file. One link for each. This site is done in PHP.

I have tried using FPDF, however, it doesn't like BMP files.

My image urls look like so: **chart.php?act=img&t=use&fy=2010&rt=Propane&mo=October** without the .bmp, however, when you right click save as... that is what you get as the only option.

Answer (score 1):

FPDF is a good route for generating the PDFs, and it can certainly handle JPG images added to the document. Which means that the only remaining task is to get those BMPs converted to JPG (or something else).

My first approach on that issue would be to question the underlying format: why do the graphs need to be BMP to begin with? The format is not very web-friendly, so to have generated the graphs in BMP in the first place creates a problem that you will have to deal with again and again and again. Why do it in the first place? Find a way to generate the graphs that gives you something useful to work with.

Assuming that you have no choice but to generate graphs in BMP, the next route would be looking at converting those BMPs into some useful format.  On the `imagecreate` manual page, a commenter provides a sample function called `ImageCreateFromBMP` which I have tested and used myself (included at the end of this answer). That will get your graphs into a file format that is actually useful, you can then write the file to disk, add it to a PDF, or offer it for download.

**Documentation and Related Reading**

- PHP `imagecreate` (source of the code in this answer) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php
- `FPDF::Image` - http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm
- pChart, a PHP chart library that does NOT create useless BMP images - http://pchart.sourceforge.net/
- JpGraph, another non-useless PHP chart library - http://jpgraph.net/
- Highcharts, interactive javascript charts that blow PHP-rendered charts out of the water - http://www.highcharts.com/

*code credit: DHKold retrieved from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php on: 13 FEB 2013*

```
<?php
/*********************************************/
/* Fonction: ImageCreateFromBMP              */
/* Author:   DHKold                          */
/* Contact:  admin@dhkold.com                */
/* Date:     The 15th of June 2005           */
/* Version:  2.0B                            */
/*********************************************/

function ImageCreateFromBMP($filename)
{
 //Ouverture du fichier en mode binaire
   if (! $f1 = fopen($filename,"rb")) return FALSE;

 //1 : Chargement des ent�tes FICHIER
   $FILE = unpack("vfile_type/Vfile_size/Vreserved/Vbitmap_offset", fread($f1,14));
   if ($FILE['file_type'] != 19778) return FALSE;

 //2 : Chargement des ent�tes BMP
   $BMP = unpack('Vheader_size/Vwidth/Vheight/vplanes/vbits_per_pixel'.
                 '/Vcompression/Vsize_bitmap/Vhoriz_resolution'.
                 '/Vvert_resolution/Vcolors_used/Vcolors_important', fread($f1,40));
   $BMP['colors'] = pow(2,$BMP['bits_per_pixel']);
   if ($BMP['size_bitmap'] == 0) $BMP['size_bitmap'] = $FILE['file_size'] - $FILE['bitmap_offset'];
   $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'] = $BMP['bits_per_pixel']/8;
   $BMP['bytes_per_pixel2'] = ceil($BMP['bytes_per_pixel']);
   $BMP['decal'] = ($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
   $BMP['decal'] -= floor($BMP['width']*$BMP['bytes_per_pixel']/4);
   $BMP['decal'] = 4-(4*$BMP['decal']);
   if ($BMP['decal'] == 4) $BMP['decal'] = 0;

 //3 : Chargement des couleurs de la palette
   $PALETTE = array();
   if ($BMP['colors'] < 16777216)
   {
    $PALETTE = unpack('V'.$BMP['colors'], fread($f1,$BMP['colors']*4));
   }

 //4 : Cr�ation de l'image
   $IMG = fread($f1,$BMP['size_bitmap']);
   $VIDE = chr(0);

   $res = imagecreatetruecolor($BMP['width'],$BMP['height']);
   $P = 0;
   $Y = $BMP['height']-1;
   while ($Y >= 0)
   {
    $X=0;
    while ($X < $BMP['width'])
    {
     if ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 24)
        $COLOR = unpack("V",substr($IMG,$P,3).$VIDE);
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 16)
     { 
        $COLOR = unpack("n",substr($IMG,$P,2));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 8)
     { 
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,$P,1));
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 4)
     {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if (($P*2)%2 == 0) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] >> 4) ; else $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x0F);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     elseif ($BMP['bits_per_pixel'] == 1)
     {
        $COLOR = unpack("n",$VIDE.substr($IMG,floor($P),1));
        if     (($P*8)%8 == 0) $COLOR[1] =  $COLOR[1]        >>7;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 1) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x40)>>6;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 2) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x20)>>5;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 3) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x10)>>4;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 4) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x8)>>3;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 5) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x4)>>2;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 6) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x2)>>1;
        elseif (($P*8)%8 == 7) $COLOR[1] = ($COLOR[1] & 0x1);
        $COLOR[1] = $PALETTE[$COLOR[1]+1];
     }
     else
        return FALSE;
     imagesetpixel($res,$X,$Y,$COLOR[1]);
     $X++;
     $P += $BMP['bytes_per_pixel'];
    }
    $Y--;
    $P+=$BMP['decal'];
   }

 //Fermeture du fichier
   fclose($f1);

 return $res;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I will put this into effect! I have been toying with the imagecreate function... not getting a result yet, but will i am sure.

Comment: Yeah, `imagecreate` alone doesn't play with BMPs; as you can see in the sample code, he has to manually unpack the palate and then manually create the image one pixel at a time. If there's any possible way to avoid dealing with BMPs at all...